# Prevent table view animation caused by keyboard input accessory view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, inputaccessoryview

I have a chat screen, which uses the view controller's `inputAccessoryView` to display a toolbar (for text input, send button + other custom types) and has a table view between the navigation bar and bottom margins.

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
    return inputToolbar
}
```

Everything works great except for one case; the initial push of the view controller. As it is being pushed on, the contents of the table view **animate up from behind** the input accessory view.

I would prefer the contents to **already be fixed above** the input accessory view - any suggested way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

get Indexpath and change UITableview content Offset based on UIKeyboard Height

```
 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if ((notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()) != nil {
            //self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
            var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
            keyboardFrame = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrame, fromView: nil)

            var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.tbl.contentInset
            contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
            self.tbl.contentInset = contentInset

            //get indexpath
            let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
            self.tbl.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexpath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if ((notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()) != nil {
            let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            self.tbl.contentInset = contentInset
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am already setting the contentInset in keyboardWillShow - still animates :( Though it may be an idea to check the animation duration on load to see if accessory input view has a lower duration I can force the contentInset to match... Will give it a bash.